# Disable default value of a column in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, data-migration, aws-dms

I know how to remove or set the default value of a column in PostgreSQL.

```
ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN price DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN price SET DEFAULT 7.77;
```

However is there a way to disable the default value of a column?

My scenario is to ingest data in a table however (I think) the default value of a column is not letting me ingest the data. I want to either disable the default value for the ingestion and then enable it or I want to drop the default values of all the tables (keeping the record of dropped values) and then set the values again to default.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: A default value on a column doesn't block an INSERT or COPY statement

Comment: Even if it is a function? like clock_timestamp() or aws_sqlserver_ext.newid() ?

Comment: "*ingest data in a table*" - what do you mean by "ingest", how exactly are you doing this? "*the default value of a column is not letting me ingest the data*" - what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Just specify a value for that column so the `DEFAULT` doesn't get used.

Comment: As has been mentioned, a column default should be no obstacle; just override it with the value you want. Perhaps you should edit your question and add some more details, so that it becomes clear what your problem is.

Comment: I think you guys are right, let me solve my problem and I will update here.